# Unable to Type in "number" input field in Chrome 93 Cypress 8.4.1

Tags: javascript, input, numbers, cypress

I am using chrome version 96 and cypress version 8.4.1. Whenever I try to type in an input field with type="number" cypress immediately fails with the error:

> InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionStart' property from
> 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not
> support selection.

HTML Code: `<input type="number" name="phone_lead" id="phone_lead" placeholder="+92 301 2345678" class="required" autocomplete="off">`

-Input Phone number:

```
cy.get('#phone_lead').click({force:true}).type('16777')
```

Any solution/suggestion how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you add your html to the question.

Comment: <input type="number" name="phone_lead" id="phone_lead" placeholder="+92 301 2345678" class="required" autocomplete="off">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't reproducible, either with Chrome 93 or 96 (you mention both versions). The test passes when using that HTML in isolation.

Technically that error comes because of the `type="number"`, from [HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)

> Note that according to the WHATWG forms spec selectionStart, selectionEnd properties and setSelectionRange method apply only to inputs of types text, search, URL, tel and password. Chrome, starting from version 33, throws an exception while accessing those properties and method on the rest of input types. **For example, on input of type number: "Failed to read the 'selectionStart' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support selection".**

But Cypress has internal checks that avoid `selectionStart` for inputs of type number,

```js
const canSetSelectionRangeElementRe = /^(text|search|URL|tel|password)$/
```

Since you are dealing with a phone number, the input type should (theoretically) be changed to `type="tel"`.

```html
<input type="tel" 
  name="phone_lead" id="phone_lead" 
  placeholder="+92 301 2345678" 
  class="required" 
  autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Thank You, changing type in html helped me fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my **React project** (other libs might experiment the same issue, or not), the only way I got `input[type="number"]` fields value writing with Cypress has been doing it like this:

```js
cy.get('input').type('{selectall}').type('123');
```

It first does a full selection of the extisting value, and later it types the value you want.

Comment: Why not try `cy.get('input').clear().type('123')` if you already have a value in the input.

Comment: @user16695029, just try it your self and you will see it doesn't work. `clear()` sets the field to `0` and if you type `123` after taht, then the value becomes `1230`.

Comment: Nope, there was no `0` in my result. You should provide the complete test, it's not reproducible from what you have given.

Comment: Same issue: when .clear() called on type=number input you get "0" in there in current Chrome 113.0.5672.92 at least  and then type just adds to that..

Answer (score 1):

Error message says what you are doing wrong. You shouldn't use click function. It is not a button and it is not a dropdown.
You need just to type in it.

Try without click:

```
cy.get('#phone_lead').type('16777')
```

Also try to use `data-cy` instead of `#phone_lead`

further reading https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices

Comment: Thanks Rohit for edits, was typing from phone. Can't mark it as code from phone

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
cy.get('input[name="phone_lead"]').type('12345678')
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation with your code please.

Comment: is it working for you?